# Custom audio player controls on notification ios

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, swift4, audio-streaming

How to implement audio Player to stream music from the url, but I don't know how to put media player controls in Notification like gaana and saavn app.
 Once user play song notification should display on notification bar and user can controls play,pause next ,rewind the audio from notification section.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhsYV.png)

Comment: please suggest us if any library available .is it possible with native iOS??.....

Comment: refer this app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/luxe-radio/id1073120504?mt=8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple, and no third party library required for it

```
import MediaPleyer
```

And add observer on remote control Like

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onPauseRemoteCommand(_:)))
MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onPlayRemoteCommand(_:)))
```

Comment: Thanx @AlokMaurya

Comment: @SPatel the notfication panel disappears as soon as its pause button is hit from the notification panel. how to retain it.

Comment: @SPatel one more thing. i have a music app, which has multiple screens like favourites, downloads, home, musicstore. as per my understanding and implementation, by just adding these two lines, notification panel will be triggered, wherever you play music from and it triggers the same function on pause command, hence the app crashes, because i need to update UI respective to whatever screen i am on. how can i manipulate this so on each screen the unique function is called which takes care of the respective screen's UI.

Comment: @UsamabinAttique Just create common object ex "PlayerManager". and register that object for remoteCommandCenter

Comment: @UsamabinAttique notification panel disappear once you set `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nil`
Make sure you'r not setting on pause event.

Comment: @SPatel common object of what? MPRemoteCommandCenter only has getters. I mean to ask object of what class, type? and no Im not setting it to nil on pause command. I haven't even called it anywhere in my code, just using what you prescribed in your answer, that's it. and in pause only updating UI of the screen.

Comment: @UsamabinAttique common mean just register once for all commandCenter event